# How to get value of parameter passed in pagechange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which is like

```
 <button class="cart" onclick="allow(this)" data-val="134" data-pcode="sdfghj">
                           car</button>
```

And the function `allow` is:

```
function allow(value)
{
    console.log(value);
    $.mobile.changePage('allow.html', {
      type: "get",
      data: {
            value:value
        },
      transition: "slideup", 
      changeHash: true
    });
}
```

And for receive and the allow.html page, I'm using

```
$(document).on( "pageinit", "#viewandgift", function( e ) {
    console.log("page loaded view and gift wala");
    var passedId = (($(this).data("url").indexOf("?") > 0) ? $(this).data("url") : window.location.href ).replace( /.*value=/, "" );
    $("#details").html(["Selected id is: '", passedId, "'"].join(""));
    console.log("--------------------------");
    console.log(passedId);
});
```

What is the correct way of extracting value at the second page? parsing the URL is not a good option.

Comment: [https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl)

Comment: What is `#viewandgift` and where does it come from? As you use jQuery, why do you not use `$('.cart').click(function(event) { // your code });` for the click event?